# Use @Validated and @Valid with spring validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-validator

I have a java bean being used to send JSON messages to a spring `@RestController` and I have bean validation setup and running just fine using `@Valid`. But I want to move to Protobuf/Thrift and move away from REST. It is an internal API and a lot of big companies have done away with REST internally. What this really means is that I no longer have control of the message objects - they are generated externally. I can't put annotations on them anymore.

So now my validation has to be programmatic. How do I do this? I have coded up a `Validator` and it works just great. But it doesn't use the nice `@Valid` annotation. I have to do the following:

```
@Service
public StuffEndpoint implements StuffThriftDef.Iface {

    @Autowired
    private MyValidator myValidator;

    public void things(MyMessage msg) throws BindException {
        BindingResult errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(msg, msg.getClass().getName());
        errors = myValidator.validate(msg);
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            throw new BindException(errors);
        } else {
            doRealWork();
        }
    }
}
```

This stinks. I have to do this in every single method. Now, I can put a lot of that into one method that throws `BindException` and that makes it one line of code to add to every method. But that's still not great.

What I want is to see it look like this:

```
@Service
@Validated
public StuffEndpoint implements StuffThriftDef.Iface {

    public void things(@Valid MyMessage msg) {
        doRealWork();
    }
}
```

And still get the same result. Remember, my bean has no annotations. And yes, I know I can use the `@InitBinder` annotation on a method. But that only works for web requests.

I don't mind injecting the correct `Validator` into this class, but I would prefer if my ValidatorFactory could pull the correct one based on the `supports()` method.

Is this possible? Is there a way to configure bean validation to actually use Spring validation instead? Do I have to hijack a Aspect somewhere? Hack into the `LocalValidatorFactory` or the `MethodValidationPostProcessor`?

Thanks.

Comment: So, you need to make Spring `Validator` works with JSR-303 validation?

Comment: Yes. Is that a thing? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I never though about combining this two approaches. But it's very interesting idea. Anyways, they have different ideology. Bean Validation throws exception in case of error, and Spring Validation collect all errors to binding result. It will not simply.

Comment: By the way, in case of `public void things(@Valid MyMessage msg)` you don't need `MyMessage` to be annotated. It will be passed to `ConstraintValidator<>` as value. You can write your own annotation for messages. But this means, you will process validation exception outside of your service class.

Comment: Maybe this is outdated... but if you all are looking for a simpler approach you could try **SpringValidatorAdapter** as explained here [How to combine JSR-303 and Spring Validator class in a service layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26733582/2201637)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Its pretty complicated thing to combine Spring validation and JSR-303 constrains. And there is no 'ready to use' way. The main inconvenience is that Spring validation uses `BindingResult`, and JSR-303 uses `ConstraintValidatorContext` as result of validation.

You can try to make your own validation engine, using Spring AOP. Let's consider, what we need to do for it. First of all, declare AOP dependencies (if you didn't yet):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.8</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using Spring of version `4.2.4.RELEASE`, but of cause you can use your own. AspectJ needed for use aspect annotation. Next step, we have to create simple validator registry:

```
public class CustomValidatorRegistry {

    private List<Validator> validatorList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addValidator(Validator validator){
        validatorList.add(validator);
    }

    public List<Validator> getValidatorsForObject(Object o) {
        List<Validator> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Validator validator : validatorList){
            if(validator.supports(o.getClass())){
                result.add(validator);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you see it is very simple class, which allow us to find validator for object. Now lets create annotation, that will be mark methods, that need to be validated:

```
package com.mydomain.validation;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomValidation {
}
```

Because of standard `BindingException` class is not `RuntimeException`, we can't use it in overriden methods. This means we need define our own exception:

```
public class CustomValidatorException extends RuntimeException {

    private BindingResult bindingResult;

    public CustomValidatorException(BindingResult bindingResult){
        this.bindingResult = bindingResult;
    }

    public BindingResult getBindingResult() {
        return bindingResult;
    }
}
```

Now we are ready to create an aspect that will do most of the work. Aspect will execute before methods, which marked with `CustomValidation` annotation:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CustomValidatingAspect {

    @Autowired
    private CustomValidatorRegistry registry; //aspect will use our validator registry


    @Before(value = "execution(public * *(..)) && annotation(com.mydomain.validation.CustomValidation)")
    public void doBefore(JoinPoint point){
        Annotation[][] paramAnnotations  =
                ((MethodSignature)point.getSignature()).getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();
        for(int i=0; i<paramAnnotations.length; i++){
            for(Annotation annotation : paramAnnotations[i]){
                //checking for standard org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated
                if(annotation.annotationType() == Validated.class){
                    Object arg = point.getArgs()[i];
                    if(arg==null) continue;
                    validate(arg);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void validate(Object arg) {
        List<Validator> validatorList = registry.getValidatorsForObject(arg);
        for(Validator validator : validatorList){
            BindingResult errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(arg, arg.getClass().getSimpleName());
            validator.validate(arg, errors);
            if(errors.hasErrors()){
                throw new CustomValidatorException(errors);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(com.springapp.mvc.validators.CustomValidation)` means, that this aspect will applied to any public methods of beans, which marked with `@CustomValidation` annotation. Also note, that to mark validated parameters we are using standard `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` annotation. But of cause we could make our custom. I think other code of  aspect is very simple and does not need any comments. Further code of example validator:

```
public class PersonValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return aClass==Person.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        Person person = (Person)o;
        if(person.getAge()<=0){
            errors.rejectValue("age", "Age is too small");
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have make tune the configuration and all ready to use:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mydomain")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class AppConfig{

    .....

    @Bean
    public CustomValidatorRegistry validatorRegistry(){
        CustomValidatorRegistry registry = new CustomValidatorRegistry();
        registry.addValidator(new PersonValidator());
        return registry;
    }    
}
```

Note, `proxyTargetClass` is `true` because we will use `cglib` class proxy.

---

Example of target method in service class:

```
@Service
public class PersonService{

    @CustomValidation
    public void savePerson(@Validated Person person){        
       ....
    }

}
```

Because of `@CustomValidation` annotation aspect will be applied, and because of `@Validated` annotation `person` will be validated. And example of usage of service in controller(or any other class):

```
@Controller
public class PersonConroller{

    @Autowired
    private PersonService service;

    public String savePerson(@ModelAttribute Person person, ModelMap model){
        try{
            service.savePerson(person);
        }catch(CustomValidatorException e){
            model.addAttribute("errors", e.getBindingResult());
            return "viewname";
        }
        return "viewname";
    }

}
```

Keep in mind, that if you will invoke `@CustomValidation` from methods of `PersonService` class, validation will not work. Because it will invoke methods of original class, but not proxy. This means, that you can invoke this methods only from outside of class (from other classes), if you want validation to be working (eg `@Transactional works same way`).

Sorry for long post. My answer is not about 'simple declarative way', and possible you will do not need it. But I was curious resolve this problem.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot of taking the time. I was starting to go down this road but just wasn't sure how far I wanted to go. Or how long it would take. What you showed wasn't really all that bad, just a few classes. Great answer.

Comment: Maybe this is outdated... but if you all are looking for a simpler approach you could try **SpringValidatorAdapter** as explained here [How to combine JSR-303 and Spring Validator class in a service layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26733582/2201637)

Answer (score 5):

I marked @Ken's answer as correct because it is. But I have taken it a little further and wanted to post what I have made. I hope anybody coming to this page will find it interesting. I might try to get it in front of the Spring folks to see if it might be something included in future releases.

The idea is to have a new annotation to replace `@Valid`. So I called it `@SpringValid`. Using this annotation would kick off the system put together above. Here are all the pieces:

**SpringValid.java**

```
package org.springframework.validation.annotation;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({METHOD, FIELD, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface SpringValid {

}
```

**SpringValidationAspect.java**

```
package org.springframework.validation;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Aspect
@Component
public class SpringValidationAspect {

  private SpringValidatorRegistry springValidatorRegistry;

  @Autowired
  public SpringValidationAspect(final SpringValidatorRegistry springValidatorRegistry) {
    this.springValidatorRegistry = springValidatorRegistry;
  }

  public SpringValidatorRegistry getSpringValidatorRegistry() {
    return springValidatorRegistry;
  }

  @Before("@target(org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated) "
      + "&& execution(public * *(@org.springframework.validation.annotation.SpringValid (*), ..)) "
      + "&& args(validationTarget)")
  public void beforeMethodThatNeedsValidation(Object validationTarget) {
    validate(validationTarget);
  }

  private void validate(Object arg) {
    List<Validator> validatorList = springValidatorRegistry.getValidatorsForObject(arg);
    for (Validator validator : validatorList) {
      BindingResult errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(arg, arg.getClass().getSimpleName());
      validator.validate(arg, errors);
      if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        throw new SpringValidationException(errors);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Spring's examples show classes annotated with `@Validated` so I wanted to keep that. The above aspect only targets classes with `@Validated` at the class-level. And, just like when you use `@Valid`, it looks for the `@SpringValid` annotation stuck to a method parameter.

**SpringValidationException.java**

```
package org.springframework.validation;

import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;

public class SpringValidationException extends RuntimeException {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private BindingResult bindingResult;

  public SpringValidationException(final BindingResult bindingResult) {
    this.bindingResult = bindingResult;
  }

  public BindingResult getBindingResult() {
    return bindingResult;
  }
}
```

**SpringValidatorRegistry.java**

```
package org.springframework.validation;

import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SpringValidatorRegistry {

  private List<Validator> validatorList = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addValidator(Validator validator) {
    validatorList.add(validator);
  }

  public List<Validator> getValidatorsForObject(Object o) {
    List<Validator> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Validator validator : validatorList) {
      if (validator.supports(o.getClass())) {
        result.add(validator);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Just like the first answer, a place to register all classes that implement Spring's `org.springframework.validation.Validator` interface.

**SpringValidator.java**

```
package org.springframework.validation.annotation;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface SpringValidator {

}
```

This is just extra sauce to make it easier to register/find `Validators`. You could register all your `Validators` by hand, or you could find them via reflection. So this part is not required, I just thought it made things easier.

**MyConfig.java**

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.SpringValidationAspect;
import org.springframework.validation.SpringValidatorRegistry;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.SpringValidator;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.Validator;

@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Bean
  public SpringValidatorRegistry validatorRegistry() {
    SpringValidatorRegistry registry = new SpringValidatorRegistry();
    Map<String, Object> validators =
        applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(SpringValidator.class);
    validators.values()
        .forEach(v -> registry.addValidator((org.springframework.validation.Validator) v));
    return registry;
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringValidationAspect springValidationAspect() {
    return new SpringValidationAspect(validatorRegistry());
  }
}
```

See, scan your classpath and look for `@SpringValidator` classes and register them. Then register the Aspect and away you go.

Here is an example of such a Validator:
**MyMessageValidator.java**

```
package com.example.validators;

import com.example.messages.MyMessage;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.SpringValidator;

@SpringValidator
public class MyMessageValidator implements Validator {

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return MyMessage.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "firstField", "{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull}",
    "firstField cannot be null");
    MyMessage obj = (MyMessage) target;
    if (obj.getSecondField != null && obj.getSecondField > 100) {
      errors.rejectField(errors, "secondField", "{javax.validation.constraints.Max}", "secondField is too big");
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the service class that uses the `@SpringValid` annotation:

**MyService.java**

```
package com.example.services;

import com.example.messages.MyMessage;

import org.springframework.validation.annotation.SpringValid;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@Validated
public class MyService {

  public String doIt(@SpringValid final MyMessage msg) {
    return "we did it!";
  }
}
```

Hope this makes sense for someone at some point. I personally think it is quite useful. A lot of companies are starting to move their internal APIs away from REST and to something like Protobuf or Thrift. You can still use Bean Validation but you have to use XML, and it isn't all that nice. So I hope this will be helpful to people who want to still do programmatic validation.

Answer (score 2):

Hope it helps someone. I've got it working by adding the following configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor;

@Configuration
public class ValidatorConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor getMethodValidationPostProcessor(){
        MethodValidationPostProcessor processor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
         processor.setValidator(this.validator());
         return processor;
     }

     @Bean
     public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator(){
         return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
     }

 }
```

The service is then annotated the same way (@Validated on the class and @Valid on the parameter) and can be injected into another bean where the method can be called directly and validation happens.

Comment: This looks correct but not working. Giving server log: Bean 'validatorConfiguration' of type [com.manishoaham.swadeshi.components.ValidatorConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d552c0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)