# Java bean validation not working with web init binder

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, bean-validation, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have a controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api/events")
public class EventController{

    @Inject
    private EventValidator eventValidator;

    @InitBinder
    @Qualifier("eventValidatior")
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
        binder.setValidator(eventValidator);
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<EventModel> save(@Valid @RequestBody EventRequest request, BindingResult result){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            //some validation
        }
        //some other logic

    }   
}
```

Then i have a `EventRequest` pojo:

```
 public class EventRequest{
 private String eventName;

 @Valid
 @NotNull
 private List<Event> events;

 //setters and getters
}
```

In my controller, I have 2 types of validation, the `InitBinder`, and also java bean validation (JSR-303) that use `@NotNull` in EventRequest class.

The problem is, if I have `BindingResult result` in the controller, the `@NotNull` annotation won't work. And even the cascaded validation in `Event` class is not working too.

Why is that, how can I have both 2 types of validation?

---

Tried to add this but still not working

```
@Configuration
public class ValidatorConfig {

 @Bean
 public LocalValidatorFactoryBean defaultValidator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
 }

 @Bean
 public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSR-303 validation is ignored when custom Validator is annotated with @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188422/jsr-303-validation-is-ignored-when-custom-validator-is-annotated-with-component)

Comment: tried the suggested method, but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`binder.setValidator(eventValidator);` will replace other registered validators.

Change to:

`binder.addValidators(eventValidator);`