# Dropwizard support for validation in non-Resource classes (JSR-303)

Tags: java, spring, dropwizard, bean-validation, spring-validator

According to [this link](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.0/docs/manual/validation.html):

> If you need to validate entities outside of resource endpoints, the validator can be accessed in the Environment when the application is first ran.

Which means that the `@Valid` below won't work and I have to programatically use the validator on the `profile` object and do something with the errors that come back:

```
public class ProfilesManager {  
    ...
    public void createProfile(@Valid Profile profile) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Profile>> errors = validator.validate(profile);
        ...
    }
}
```

In Spring Boot, all I have to do is annotate it with `@Validated` and a `ConstraintViolationException` will automatically be thrown:

```
@Validated
@Component
public class ProfilesManager { 
    public void createProfile(@Valid Profile profile) {
        // if invalid, exception thrown before getting here
    }
}
```

Is there an equivalent solution for Dropwizard, official or 3rd party?

Comment: which type of exception please past this exception

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501348/how-to-combine-jsr-303-and-spring-validator-class-in-a-service-layer?rq=1

Comment: @AK.Sharma, I'm looking for a solution for Dropwizard actually

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to implement this on your own using [HK2's interception service](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/extensibility.html#interception). All you need to do is provide a `MethodInteceptor` that inspects the method parameters for the `@Valid` annotation and validate those parameters with the `Validator`

```
public class ValidationMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            Parameter parameter = invocation.getMethod().getParameters()[i];
            if (parameter.getAnnotation(Valid.class) != null) {
                handleValidation(args[i]);
            }
        }
        return invocation.proceed();
    }

    private void handleValidation(Object arg) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations
                = validator.validate(arg);

        if (!constraintViolations.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "constraint violations in bean argument");
        }
    }
}
```

In your `InterceptionService` implementation, you can decide which services should be validated with a custom `Filter` that looks for a custom `@Validated` annotation on the service class

```
public class ValidatedFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Descriptor descriptor) {
        try {
            return Class.forName(descriptor.getImplementation())
                    .isAnnotationPresent(Validated.class);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

public class ValidationInterceptionService implements InterceptionService {

    private final static MethodInterceptor METHOD_INTERCEPTOR = new ValidationMethodInterceptor();
    private final static List<MethodInterceptor> METHOD_LIST = Collections.singletonList(METHOD_INTERCEPTOR);

    @Override
    public Filter getDescriptorFilter() {
        return new ValidatedFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public List<MethodInterceptor> getMethodInterceptors(Method method) {
        for (Parameter parameter: method.getParameters()) {
            if (parameter.isAnnotationPresent(Valid.class)) {
                return METHOD_LIST;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ConstructorInterceptor> getConstructorInterceptors(Constructor<?> c) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

See complete example with test case in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/psamsotha/service-validation-example).

Comment: This is an interesting solution and is similar to how Spring does it. However, keep in mind my goal is to enable all the features in the Bean Validation framework, including `@Min`, `@Max`, custom annotations, etc. In method and class levels. Or in other words, I'm looking for a Dropwizard version of `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor`, but it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: You could try to just ignore the check for `@Valid` and validate everything.

Comment: If you have an attribute like `@Min(0) int age` and you call `.validate(age)`, it won't work. Which means I'd have to create wrappers for everything, so I can put the annotations in attributes rather than parameters.

Comment: You know you can integrate Spring with Dropwizard. You can just use Spring at the service level.